# Coldfusion consuming webservice -> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, timeout, connection, axis

I'm consuming a webservice over Coldfusion 9 for getting property data and saving the result to our local database. The script gets executed via scheduler once a day. The problem is that **sometimes** it throws an error (see below).

Basically I'm getting a list of IDs (one request to get this list) and loop over the result with one webservice request for every ID (~150 requests).

Sadly I can't get the detailed data for all properties in one request.

I tried already setting `-Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=10000` in the JVM Arguments - same result ...

```
"Error","jrpp-7225","10/22/11","03:00:32",,"Cannot perform web service invocation properties.
The fault returned when invoking the web service operation is:
AxisFault
    faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/} Server.userException
    faultSubcode:
        faultString: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out 
        faultActor:
            faultNode:
                faultDetail: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
                at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
                at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
                at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor191.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.axis.components.net.DefaultSocketFactory.create(DefaultSocketFactory.java:15...
```

Any ideas on this one? What is causing the timeout: a slow remote server? our server which cannot open more sockets for new connections?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to do the webservice requests in smaller batches. Use a DB or some other persisted variable to store the initial list of 150 ids, and then do 1-50, 51-100, etc in separate `cfschedule` calls. You can update the properties of the scheduled job in code to set the interval to 61 seconds while processing the batch, and then reset it to the original values once all batches are complete.

Comment: The error seems to occur on every index of the loop. Any other suggestions? Any idea how to increase the timeoutlimit (applicationwide would be great but serverwide would be ok too)?